# Trying to use Justify-content-around but content not spreading out

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to spread some spans evenly as shown in [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) bootstrap documentation but it is not spreading the spans out. Trying to use justify-content-around like in the documentation. What am I missing? Thank you. My full code can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/BaajLZm?editors=1010).

HTML

```
    <div class="row section-header d-flex justify-content-around" style="padding: 5px; background-color: #7C9DB9">
        <div class="col-12">
            <span class="header-span" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="update($index, tab.value)" ng-class="{'span-active': tab.active}">
                {{tab.label}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were applying the flex properties to the incorrect `div` elements. Try this:

```
<div class="section-header" style="padding: 5px; background-color: #7C9DB9">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="header-span" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="update($index, tab.value)" ng-class="{'span-active': tab.active}">
      {{tab.label}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used `div` instead of `span` as well. You can also combine the first two div elements to lighten the DOM.